# How to manage DirectoryInfo writing/reading exceptions?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to manage DirectoryInfo writing/reading exceptions?

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tbKeresesHelye.Text);
 foreach (var f in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
 {
   richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + f.Directory + "\\" + f.Name + " >> " + f.Length + "\n";
 }
```

Comment: what is youre question

Comment: Not really answering the question, but use `StringBuilder` when doing string processing in loops - it's way faster.

Comment: where are your exceptions?

Comment: file / folder (var f) can not be read

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
string address = "D:";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(address);
try
  {
     foreach (var f in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {         
        richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(f.DirectoryName + f.Name + " >> " + f.Length + "\n")));
     }
   }
catch (Exception ex)
   {
       richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(ex.Message)));
   }
```

Just for your information, it is good practice of exception handling like that:

- The most exact exception
- The less exact exception
- the common exception

And  use the `throw` keyword without an identifier to preserve the original
exception details like that:

```
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    throw;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```